Pandas Groupby 2 column but turn one of the column that I grouped by a column in display
Here's the data in pandas dataframe:



Hour
Country




1
Indonesia


1
USA


2
India


3
Indonesia


3
Indonesia



I want to aggregate them like this:



hour\country
Indonesia
USA
India




1
1
1
0


2
0
0
1


3
2
0
0



I tried to do this:
df.groupby(['hour','country']).count()
but it turned into this:



hour
country
count




1
India
0



USA
1



Indonesia
1


2
India
1



USA
0



Indonesia
0


3
India
0



USA
0



Indonesia
2



How to make the unique values of the country into column instead?

Use pivot tables : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table

out = pd.crosstab(df["Hour"], df["Country"]).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index(names="Hour/Country") ?
